# Correctly distributing spacing when iPhone / iPad is rotated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I understand how to fix a UI element against any side of of a view, using the Autosizing in Interface Builder, but how would I properly distribute elements so that are evenly spaced out whenever the device is rotated. In this case the elements are evenly distributed, but bunched on one side.

```
-----------------
|               |
| * * * * * *   |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------

------------------------
|                      |
|  *  *  *  *  *  *    |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply do not fix them to either left or right, that will happen.

Comment: I don't think that is true if the elements are bunched on one side

Comment: If they start out evenly distributed, they will stay evenly distributed when the device is rotated. If they start out bunched on one side, they will stay bunched on one side, but the spacing will increase approximately proportionally to the width.